# .ahk script remade for LGS

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

i have been looking all round but with no success on trying to convert myself this little piece of code from .ahk into Logitech Gaming Software to use as a macro. Could some1 help with it? please help

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

; Nels
NRA := 1

; SS
Insert::Suspend

; NR
*~LButton::
    while GetKeyState("LButton") & NRA
    {    
        DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, -2, int, 2, uint, 1, int, 0)
        Sleep, 9.5
        DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, 1.75, int, 1, uint, 0, int, 0)
        Sleep, 5
    }
return
```